# checking objects' expiration date for removal in the background

Tags: java, multithreading, datetime

I've got a list of objects with expiration date,and the objects should be removed from the list at the specified date and time.

But this should be done in the background while a user is working with the program. How can i do so? is multi threading the way to go or are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Threads are the native way to solve that, if youre using Modern frameworks you can use his features like cron expressions, jobs, events, etc...

But if you case is a native java app a Thread with a while(appRunning) comparing the date in a interval should work.